# How to get a type parameter's class name?

Tags: kotlin

I have a base class:

```kotlin
abstract class JSONDeserializationStrategy<T : Any>: DeserializationStrategy<T> {
    protected abstract fun parse(json: JsonObject): T

    protected abstract fun getSerializationException(): SerializationException

}
```

and then a derived class

```kotlin
class MyClassParserDeserializationStrategy : JSONDeserializationStrategy<MyClass>() {

    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor 
               = buildClassSerialDescriptor("MyClass")

    override fun getSerializationException(): SerializationException 
               = throw SerializationException("Invalid JSON received for MyClass.")
```

How could I move the property `descriptor` and the method `getSerializationException` from the derived class into the base class, since they only "adapt" by providing their name as String? I was trying to do something in the direction of `T::class.java.simpleName as String` but it didnt work. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I took the liberty to edit the title, because you're not trying to access the derived class's name (which would be the class of the serializer, and is definitely accessible from the base class). Instead, you're trying to access the class name of the type parameter.

Comment: thank you! (And sorry)

Answer (score 2):

As @Tenfour04 explained, `T` is erased, so it is not directly accessible. However, as long as the subclass of `JSONDeserializationStrategy` provides the `T` as a specific class/type, it can be acquired with a bit of reflection voodoo:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val strategy = MyClassParserDeserializationStrategy()
    println(strategy.descriptor.serialName)  // MyClass
}

abstract class JSONDeserializationStrategy<T : Any>: DeserializationStrategy<T> {
    protected val type: KType = this::class.supertypes
        .first { it.classifier == JSONDeserializationStrategy::class }
        .arguments[0].type!!

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    protected val typeClass = requireNotNull(type.classifier as? KClass<T>) {
        "T is unknown"
    }

    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = buildClassSerialDescriptor(typeClass.simpleName!!)

    fun getSerializationException(): SerializationException =
        throw SerializationException("Invalid JSON received for ${typeClass.simpleName!!}.")

    ...
}
```

I'm not 100% sure, but I believe both `type!!` and `simpleName!!` are safe, they can't be null.

Also, it won't work if `T` is really fully erased and unknown, e.g.:

```kotlin
val strategy = GenericParserDeserializationStrategy<MyClass>() // exception
```

For this reason it makes sense to open `type`/`typeClass` properties for overriding, so generic non-abstract subclasses could provide their own means to acquire `T`. However, then we would probably need to move the initialization of most of properties outside of the constructor.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea type is not fully erased, I suppose only in the case where type is explicitly defined as part of a supertype of a class.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'm not fully confident about this stuff, it's pretty hacky, but my understanding is that we use the fact that bytecode stores info that e.g. our `StringList` type was declared as `List<String>`. Even if `List` generally can't access its `T`, it can acquire its runtime type and if it is `StringList` then `List` can check that `StringList` was declared as `List<String>`. Of course, that doesn't mean type erasure is no longer a problem. This technique can only be used in cases when we expect to have a separate subclass per each `T`. I believe this is the case in OP's problem.

Comment: @broot thank you so much ! i have to keep looking at this... i was trying the answer from Tenfour but it breaks when I pass List<A>::class.

Comment: If you need to use it in situations when `T` is itself a parameterized type (`List<A>`) then note such types can't be expressed as `KClass` and you need to use `KType` which is kind of more low-level and harder to use. My example used `KClass`, so it probably won't work for you, it will only show `List` or something like that. For this reason I kept `KType` in a separate `type` property and you need to use it instead of `typeClass`. You may have problems getting its name exactly as you need though.

Comment: @broot thanks a lot for taking time to reply, let me take a moment to say i appreciate that you have been answering my questions since the beginning of october where I started learning Kotlin. I learned about the TypeToken pattern as a way to get around getting the type of generics but I think this is a bit of code that maybe my use case doesn't require... Technically I could skip all this part by calling kotlin's deserialization decodeFromString<A>(json) but they say this is still in experimental so I thought I should stay away from that (and not put experimental things into production code).

Comment: I'm glad to hear that :-) And grats for identifying this pattern as "TypeToken". I didn't mention that, but this is in fact the same technique we used in good old Java for creating arbitrary `Type` objects.

Answer (score 1):

Because of type erasure, T's class is not accessible. Work-around could be to add it as a constructor property that returns the type, and then the subclasses must pass the type. The property needs to be in the constructor, rather than provided as an abstract property for subclasses to override because you need it to initialize `descriptor` at instantiation time. (It's highly discouraged to call an open property at class initialization time.)

```
abstract class JSONDeserializationStrategy<T : Any>(protected val typeClass: KClass<out T>): DeserializationStrategy<T> {
    protected abstract fun parse(json: JsonObject): T

    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = buildClassSerialDescriptor(typeClass.simpleName!!)

    fun getSerializationException(): SerializationException =
        throw SerializationException("Invalid JSON received for ${typeClass.simpleName}.")
}

class TodaySaleParserDeserializationStrategy : JSONDeserializationStrategy<TodaySale>(TodaySale::class) {

}
```

Comment: thank you so much for this reply. This is the way I went with but when I pass in the constructor  List<A>::class then it breaks... for now I am passing List<A> as a string manually input-ted but a workaround would be great... i am not 100% confident on the reply from broot... but I need to look at it longer.